# how to find contact id on item click of listview

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, android-listview

I am beginner in android technology.I have a listview in which my contact names are shown, I want when i click on listview item, contact id of particular contact is shown in toast. I tried a lot but not able to do that.also doesn't found suitable example on google

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listcontact = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    getnumber(this.getContentResolver());
    listcontact.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /*  ContentResolver cr2 = null;
            Cursor phone2 = cr2.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
            String uid=phone2.getString(phone2.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));*/
            String getselected=(String)(listcontact.getItemAtPosition(arg2));
            long getsele=(long)(listcontact.getItemIdAtPosition(arg2));
            String s=String.valueOf(getsele);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //phoneCall(getselected);
            //Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            //callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0377778888"));
            //startActivity(callIntent);
        }
    });

    edittext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    edittext.requestFocus();
    edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
public void getnumber(ContentResolver cr) {
    Cursor phone = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    while (phone.moveToNext()) {
        phonenumber=phone.getString(phone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        name=phone.getString(phone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        System.out.println("...........name");
        String list=name+
                " "+phonenumber;
        aa.add(list);
    }
    phone.close();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,aa);
    listcontact.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: String id =phone.getString(phone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID));

Comment: Mayuri I want contact id in itemclick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have an ArrayAdapter of String. That means the content of every row in the ListView is a String. In your case is:

```
 name 12121212121
```

you retrieve (almost) correctly the content of the row, this way:

```
String getselected=(String)(listcontact.getItemAtPosition(arg2));
```

getselected will contain something like `name 12121212121`.

Imo, since you are already working with cursor, You should use one of the implementations of   `CursorAdapter`,

The simplest thing that you can do is to split the string for empty space, but of course, if the String is `name surname 12121212121` it will not work that good. Another thing you can do is to wrap the information inside a class:

```
class Info {
  public String name;
  public String phone;

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return name + " " + phone;
  } 
}
```

your adapter will be of `Info` and

```
String getselected=(String)(listcontact.getItemAtPosition(arg2));
```

will change like

```
Info getselected=(Info)(listcontact.getItemAtPosition(arg2));
```

name will be `getselected.name` and phone will be `getselected.phone`.

Comment: thanks for answering, but not worked - "Unfortunately application has been stopped"

Comment: you are right, sometimes i have ABC XYZ +65 56 255 456. how to separate phone number and name because on item click, i have to call on that number.

Comment: I explained it in the answer. Read it carefully

Comment: thanks a lot sir. it is working perfectly. i forget to change adapter type,

Answer (score 1):

Try That

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
       long getsele=(long)(listcontact.get(arg3));
}
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Make A Class

```
class Info {
  public String name;
  public String phone;
  public String id;
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return name + " " + phone;
  } 
}
```

Update your method

```
 public void getnumber(ContentResolver cr) {
        Cursor phone = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        while (phone.moveToNext()) {
              Info info = new Info();

            info.phone = phone.getString(phone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            info.name = phone.getString(phone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        info.id =phone.getString(phone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID‌​));
            System.out.println("...........name");         
            aa.add(info);
        }
        phone.close();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,aa);
        listcontact.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

listcontact.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         int  Id= ((Info)aa.get(arg2)).id; 
        }});
```

Comment: thanks @user1211209 your answer helped me. +1 for you

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
           int viewId= arg1.getId()// this will return you the id of that particular view
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
    list_View.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position,
                        long arg3) {

    TextView txt_content        = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_content);
    String uid = txt_content.getText().toString();

// work if you have uid into this textView
});
```

Hope this could help

Answer (score 0):

First of all add your all the data to HashMap or in ArrayList. Then when you click on row, at that time use that ArrayList or HashMap to fetch the data whatever you want.

i.e.

```
 ArrayList<String> idArray=new ArrayList<String>();

idArray.add(YOUR DATA);
```

Then, When you click on row,

```
String id= idArray.get(arg2);
```

i.e.

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mainData=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); 
HashMap<String, String> data=new HashMap<String, String>();

data.put("id", YOUR ID DATA);
data.put("name", YOUR NAME DATA);
```

At the end of insertion in HashMap, Just add that hashmap into mainData ArrayList.

```
mainData.add(data);
```

Then, use this arraylist to fetch your records,

```
String id= mainData.get(arg2).get("id");
String name= mainData.get(arg2).get("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store contact id at the time of retriving contact and set tag on listview item. After that you can get id onItem click event of listview by v.gettag()